# Jquery submenu should have a selected class on click

Tags: jquery, addclass, submenu, removeclass

On click the submenu  *go to first slide* - *go to second slide* - *go to third slide*
it should go to tab3 with a selected class.
not sure what I'm missing.

http://jsfiddle.net/L7R9D/9/

```
$('a.see-all').on('click', function (e){
    $('a.see-all').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.select-options a').removeClass("selected");
    $('.submenu').addClass("selected");
    $('.tab-content').hide();
    $('#third').show();
});
```

Comment: Well, either your code works just fine, or I don't understand what you meant... When I click on the red sub-menus, the "tab three" menu appears bold.

Comment: Is based on my DEMO, did you check my demo? it will make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were adding selected to the clicked link but in a line of code just under it you were removing selected again.  `$('.select-options a').removeClass("selected");`  You need to move it to the top It will remove all the selected classes from all the links.  And then you can proceed to add the new selected links from there.

```
$('a.see-all').on('click', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.select-options a').removeClass("selected"); 
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('.submenu').addClass("selected");
        $('.tab-content').hide();
        $('#third').show();
});
```